# Rollup job making max aggregation of a date field to be float instead of date

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, rollup

I have created an ElasticSearch rollup job using Kibana 7.6.0. One of the aggregations is a Max for a date field and expects the type to be a date but the generated mappings made the type float. How can this mapping be updated or is there a way of manually specifying the type of each aggregation using the Kibana console?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change mappings in Elasticsearch after the index is created.  You need to create a mapping entry for the index that specifies the "date" field as a float type.  After you'll need to either re-index the index with the bad field type or re-run the rollup job into a new index.

Here's info on creating a mapping entry: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html